# Soundcloud embedded javascript error : Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas width is 0

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm getting a uncaught InvalidStateError, from soundcloud embedded profiles from `(https://w.soundcloud.com/player/widget-6c3640e3.js & https://w.soundcloud.com/player/multi-sounds-0e392418.js)`  on my site [pullup.club](http://pullup.club/) it's hosted off of github.io and is [open source](https://github.com/pullup/pullup.github.io/blob/gh-pages/index.html)...

I have two embedded soundcloud profiles in a modal popup

```
  <iframe width="35%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/5142431&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

and when my site is loaded I get errors and a bit of lag, not sure how to get rid of this error, and was wondering if it was because I have the embedded players in a popup, or if I need to somehow specify the canvas size?

I'm completely clueless, so all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is loading it in an invisible popup indeed.
So at the time soundcloud's js code is called within the iframe there is no space for the canvas to spread in and so the width of it is 0.

Solution1: create the iframe on the fly using jquery after the popup is shown. (assuming your site uses jquery, which the one you mentioned in the question does)

Solution2: Let the div containing the soundcloud frames render outside the screen, then move it into visible area

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem can be that the containing `<div>` is a flexible `width` without `min-width`.

One fix for this error is to change the `width` of the `<iframe>` to `px` value rather than a % value, as the width of the `<div>` is determined by its content.

Example:

```
<iframe width="350px"...>
```

The other fix is to establish the `width` the `<div>` containing the % `<iframe>` to a `px/vw` value.